# Randomize a text on screen with design

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using a PHP to connect to store the input text and after retrieving the text from the database I want to randomize it on the html but i don't know how
i think in jquery or css ??
i attached an image to show how the output look
[image]
here's a part of my code below
my code:

```
<form action="" method="Post" >
   <input type='text' name='answer1' placeholder="input" >
     <input type='sumbit' value='sumbit' >
        </form>
            </div>
<div class="randomizedText">
    <?php echo gettext( $freqData ) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You better read about `<canvas>` and `javascript` to get text vertical OR create an image with the php image functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically generating a word cloud?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307738/dynamically-generating-a-word-cloud)

Comment: If you're open to libraries, [this one](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) uses D3 to make word clouds.  I've used it before, pretty easy and robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQCloud](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/) or if you want you can download and use Awesome Tag Cloud using Jquery and Canvas HTML5 from [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Awesome-Tag-Cloud-Plugin-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas-awesomeCloud.html)

**BASIC USAGE**

1. Load the latest version of jQuery library and jQuery awesomeCloud plugin in the document.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.awesomeCloud.min.js"></script>
```

2. Wrap the words/tags in an HTML element with a data-weight attribute that reflects it's "weight".

```
<div id="demo"> 
<span data-weight="91"> Tag 1 </span>
<span data-weight="21"> Tag 2 </span> 
<span data-weight="41"> Tag 3 </span> 
<span data-weight="13"> Tag 4 </span> 
<span data-weight="78"> Tag 5 </span> 
...
</div>
```

3. Call the plugin on the parent element and set the options for the tag cloud.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo").awesomeCloud({
"size" : {
"<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/grid/">grid</a>" : 16, // word spacing, smaller is more tightly packed
"factor" : 0, // font resize factor, 0 means automatic
"normalize" : false // reduces outliers for more attractive output
},
"color" : {
"background" : "rgba(255,255,255,0)", // background color, transparent by default
"start" : "#20f", // color of the smallest font, if options.color = "gradient""
"end" : "rgb(200,0,0)" // color of the largest font, if options.color = "gradient"
},
"options" : {
"color" : "random-dark", // random-light, random-dark, gradient
"rotationRatio" : 0.35, // 0 is all horizontal, 1 is all vertical
"printMultiplier" : 3, // set to 3 for nice printer output; higher numbers take longer
"sort" : "random" // highest, lowest or random
},
"font" : "'Times New Roman', Times, serif", //  the CSS font-family string
"shape" : "square" // circle, square, star or a theta function describing a shape
});
});
</script>
```

For more Advanced Usages, please check the [demo page](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Awesome-Tag-Cloud-Plugin-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas-awesomeCloud/) or visit the official website.